# What are the disadvantages of sharing a single sqlite connection (or any database connection) with multiple threads?

Tags: database, multithreading, sqlite, thread-safety, database-connection

I have read on several [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739590/how-to-share-single-sqlite-connection-in-multi-threaded-python-application) on stackoverflow.. which advise on using a separate connection for each thread but does not mention what are the bad effects of not doing so. Can you please explain what are the concurrency issues or latency/speed issues for reads or writes when using the same connection for multiple threads.

Also why a new connection be used for each thread ?
Also, what does it mean.. when somebody mentions that it is 'thread-safe' ?

Comment: Threads run asynchronously. Consider what happens when one threads starts/ends a transaction.