# Inserting in sqlite with each thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I am trying to insert in a SQLITE database the new response I get from my API on each thread for 3 different cities. However I get an error on the execute command as I seem to be unable to insert the values as a weather['main']['temp'] or even if I give it to a variable y = weather['main']['temp'] it still doesn't work. I would welcome any suggestions

```
import requests
import json
import threading
import time
from threading import Thread
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("dfg.db",check_same_thread = False)
c = conn.cursor()

def main():
    createT()
    threading.Timer(10, giveVelingrad).start()
    threading.Timer(15, giveSofia).start()
    threading.Timer(25, givePlovdiv).start()

def createT():
        c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabl(city TEXT, temp REAL)')    

def giveVelingrad():
    city = "Velingrad"
    response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +city+ "&appid=2e8707d1eb97fbbba33ef766d9ed80ac&units=metric")
    weather = response.json()
    www = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H.%M.%S")
    y = weather['name']
    z = weather['main']['temp']
    c.execute("INSERT INTO tabl VALUES (?, ?)",y,z )
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
    print("\n",www)
    print("The weather for ", weather['name'])
    print("The temperature is ", weather['main']['temp'])

def giveSofia():
    city = "Sofia"
    response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +city+ "&appid=2e8707d1eb97fbbba33ef766d9ed80ac&units=metric")
    weather = response.json()
    www = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H.%M.%S")
    print("\n",www)
    print("The weather for ", weather['name'])
    print("The temperature is ", weather['main']['temp'])

def givePlovdiv():
    city = "Plovdiv"
    response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +city+ "&appid=2e8707d1eb97fbbba33ef766d9ed80ac&units=metric")
    weather = response.json()
    www = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H.%M.%S")
    print("\n",www)
    print("The weather for ", weather['name'])
    print("The temperature is ", weather['main']['temp'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You need to pass in parameters as *one* sequence: `c.execute("INSERT INTO tabl VALUES (?, ?)", [y, z])` or `c.execute("INSERT INTO tabl VALUES (?, ?)", (y, z))`, not as two separate arguments. Don't share the connection between threads.

Comment: Thank you it did work! I didn't understand your last sentence what do you mean by not sharing my connection?

Comment: I misunderstood, you only use the connection in one thread, sorry.

Comment: No,my whole project is to do the exact same thing in all of my threads and fill my database this way. What is the problem with that and how can I avoid it? EDIT: Sorry, saw that you answered before I even asked in your Answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in parameters as *one* sequence: `c.execute("INSERT INTO tabl VALUES (?, ?)", [y, z])` or `c.execute("INSERT INTO tabl VALUES (?, ?)", (y, z))`, not as two separate arguments.

You also don't want to share the connection between threads, and certainly don't share cursors between threads; I'd use a separate connection per thread. See [How to share single SQLite connection in multi-threaded Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739590/how-to-share-single-sqlite-connection-in-multi-threaded-python-application)

Comment: You're completely right. Moreover, there is no point to share connection between threads because there is no benefit of using threads then.