# Is it okay to use only one cursor to execute all operations with database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a program, which must work with database (and it can work in few threads). I wrote a special class, which starts from:

```
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
         self.connection = sqlite3.connect("some_db.db", check_same_thread=False)
         self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Is it okay to use such class? Or I should go another way and use few cursors? My program works fine now and I didn't notice any problems, but I'm not sure can it lead to big problems in future

Comment: You mention threads and it's clear you're using SQLite: see [How to share single SQLite connection in multi-threaded Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739590/how-to-share-single-sqlite-connection-in-multi-threaded-python-application) for some potential issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sqlite3 working in classes and I don't need it to be self-ed. Ive got it like...

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("some_db.db")
c = connection.cursor()
```

Yeah I think its fine, until you need multiple databases where all you need to do is name you connection and cursors something different like...

```
connection2 = sqlite3.connect("another_db.db")
c2 = connection2.cursor()
```

You can have them running at the same time too. Just remember to commit and close when you don't need them anymore.