# Low latency flask-sqlalchemy encrypted DB

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pysqlcipher

Per the docs here: https://pydoc.dev/sqlalchemy/latest/sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.pysqlcipher.html

We connect to a DB using `sqlite+pysqlcipher://:password@/dbname.db`

But according to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173197/557406 using the key instead of the password results in much better performance. Is it possible to specify a key when connecting to an encrypted DB using flask-sqlalchemy? Are there any other important settings to use to avoid taking a noticeable performance hit when using an encrypted DB?