# How to sync SQLite DB in cores created by python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, sqlite, multiprocessing

I have a class named 'DbWorker' to access data in SQlite DB. I design parallel procedure to create 3 cores by python multiprocessing. Each processors has 'DbWorker' object to process data and access DB.

Now I encountered a problem explained as follows:

```
time1: core-1: update data and insert them in DB
time2: core-2: look-up DB, but no data in DB
time3: core-3: the same problem as core-2
time4: core-1: look-up DB and DB has updated data
```

I found an article [How to share a single SQLite connection in multi-threaded Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739590/how-to-share-single-sqlite-connection-in-multi-threaded-python-application). 
Then I used 'Lock' to avoid data competition, but nothing's happened.

Is there any way to solve this problem??

Eric

Comment: Does DbWorker commit the transaction after writing to db?

Comment: yes, I run `session.commit()` after `session.add(data)` immediately.